# Can visual select mode be integrated with the Unix selection clipboard?

Tags: visual-mode, gvim, mouse, os-clipboard, unix

Is it possible to configure vim (obviously with `:set mouse=a`) and/or gvim such that the visual selection modes automatically integrate with X's selection buffer?

I am aware of how to setup the copy registers to integrate with the clipboard, but I would like to integrate the selection system as well. Is it possible and, if so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim) .... This is covered in (my) accepted answer I think (unless I misunderstood the question): *"if you use gVim, you can get copy-on-select behaviour when using `:set guioptions+=a`. This is enabled by default on X11 systems (copies to PRIMARY)*"

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Only part of this is covered in that (useful) post and I believe this somewhat different use case deserves specific treatment. Making this a duplicate will not make it easier to sort out for people with this specific goal in mind.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that you are set up with the features necessary for copy and pasting with the system clipboard, but I want to be a tad redundant as those registers can be a tad challenging to set up. It's all about the features that are enabled with your install of Vim. In OS X and Linux, the clipboard feature needs to be enabled, and Linux usually also requires the xterm_clipboard setting. You can tell if these are set by running `vim --version` and seeing if there is a `+` or `-` for on or off respectively next to the feature name. There are notes on how to do this with [OS X here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677986/vim-copy-selection-to-os-x-clipboard), and [Ubuntu here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347519/unable-to-copy-from-vim-to-system-clipboard). There is also a [nice summary of this information on a blog here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/accessing-the-system-clipboard-from-vim/).

According to [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/348207/prevent-macvim-copying-every-visual-selection-to-clipboard), macvim (and most likely gvim in general) will (assuming the clipboard is set up properly) automatically copy selections into the system clipboard if `set guioptions+=a` is set. This seems to be the key to working with X's selection buffer. Quickly viewing the [Vim documentation on guioptions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27guioptions%27), putting `set guioptions+=a` should do as you desire for gVim. For more info check out this post [by Carpetsmoker here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim).

For console Vim I found this [article on how to disable what you are after](http://choorucode.com/2014/05/20/how-to-disable-autoselect-in-vim/)... it seems that putting the following in your `.vimrc` will result in happy days:

```
 set clipboard += autoselect
```

For me, this successfully copied visual selections into the `+` register.

Comment: In my vim, `set clipboard += autoselect` fails with `E518: Unknown option: autoselect`. Version 8.0 on ubuntu 17.10.