# How to disable the clipboard being overwritten when highlighting text in visual block mode?

Tags: visual-mode, os-clipboard

Say I've got a URL in the clipboard, I enter vim, I hit `<C-Q>` and highlight a word. Then I hit `I<C-R>+` to insert the clipboard at the start of the selection.

What actually happens is the word that I had highlighted gets inserted, instead of the URL I was expecting.

I've got `clipboard=`, `selectmode=key`, `virtualedit=block`. I can't find any other setting I might have enabled to do this. I've confirmed that `:reg +` shows the URL and then changes after I highlight the word.

Comment: wait a related question, I've got `guioptions=ac`, the `a` is suspect. http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/769/can-visual-select-mode-be-integrated-with-the-unix-selection-clipboard?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Removing `a` from the list of `guioptions` was the answer. Change it from `set guioptions=ac` to only `set guioptions=c`.

Credit to carpetsmoker in the comments here [Can visual select mode be integrated with the Unix selection clipboard?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/769/can-visual-select-mode-be-integrated-with-the-unix-selection-clipboard?rq=1)