# How do I copy and paste between two Vim instances - shared clipboard?

Tags: command-line, cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard

I use gnu `screen` and I run `vim file1.txt` and `vim file2.txt` in two windows.

How can I copy part of the text from `file1.txt` and paste it to `file2.txt`
without using temporary files or opening two files under the same Vim instance?

Basically I would like to yank in first window and paste in second one. I need shared clipboard.

Comment: Do you consider to open `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` using one instance? E.g. `vim file1.txt file2.txt`?

Comment: @kenorb no. It's written in the question.

Comment: In `tmux`, you can start "copy mode" with `prefix+[`, then `space` to select stuff`, `Enter` to copy, then go to the other pane, and use `prefix+]` to paste ... It's very similar to Vim's visual mode. IIRC `screen` can do this as well (but I don't remember how, as I haven't used it in years and years).

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: @hippietrail linux, no gui.

Comment: how about `cat file1.txt` and copy the content and paste the content to file2.txt?

Comment: You can also `:set mouse=` to prevent vim from taking over the mouse, allowing you to use the system clipboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to just copy it to the system clipboard from the first instance, then copy it from the system clipboard in the second instance.  How exactly you would do this depends on your OS and also your vim `clipboard` setting.

Another option is to use [vim-easyclip](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-easyclip) which has the ability to share one clipboard across all vim instances (including sharing a history of yanks as well).  Internally what it does is mirror your clipboard to a temporary file, so it bypasses using your system clipboard entirely.

Comment: +1 for `vim-easyclip`

Answer (score 4):

I usually end up using [xsel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) to copy to/from the system clipboard:

```
vmap <leader>y !xsel -i -b && xsel -b <CR>
nmap <leader>p :r !xsel -b <CR>
```

Comment: This is great! However, I didn't like that the "yank" mapping replaces the selection with itself; it counts as a change in the undo tree, and flags the file as modified even if you only yanked something. I ended up with `:vmap <leader>y :w !wl-copy <CR> <CR>` to get rid of the redundant change. This way, the command is "write-only". The extra CR gets rid of vim pausing to show you the command output. Change `wl-paste` to `xsel -i -b` for X11 I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your environment. Basically, we're talking about inter-process communications and this is very much OS specific.

You can use:

1. System clipboard
2. Tmux or screen buffer
3. tmp file

Comment: @A B I am on Linux, I don't want to use gnu screen buffer or tmp file. How do I use system clipboard from vim?

Comment: @name http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim/96#96 - though I think that requires X-forwarding if you're on SSH.

Comment: @name Please define *system clipboard*

Comment: @muru this is only assumption that screen is remote. Many folks are using screen/tmux - locally

Comment: @AB  I work remotely ssh + screens + vims. I am fine with using remote's host system clipboard and not the client's one.

Comment: @AB "if you're on SSH"

Comment: @muru (I think that) X-forwarding is only required if you want to use your *local* system clipboard over SSH. You can still use the remote machine's system clipboard from within Vim without it.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve that by just installing gvim, the grafical version of vim, you don't have to use it or anything. It solves this problem and lets you even put stuff you copied outside vim.

edit: Install gvim and put `set clipboard=unnamedplus` on your vimrc

Comment: Welcome to this site! I am really not sure your answer is right: Could you explain _how_ installing gVim would solve the issue of sharing a clipboard between two different vim instances?

Comment: I think installing Gvim on some systems enables the `+cliipboard` feature, allowing the usage of the `"*`register. I can't test it right now though.

Comment: Yes, by installing gvim you enable vim to copy from the +clipboard. But I answer was incomplete, you should also put `set clipboard=unnamedplus` on your vimrc

Comment: That's only if you want Vim to copy to the `"+` register by default. Without it, you can still use `"+yy`, for example to copy a line to the system clipboard. If you truly want your answer to be complete, you could explain 1/ why install Gvim 2/ how to use the `"+` register 3/ what `set clipboard=unnamedplus` does.

Answer (score 0):

I use a temporary file:

Put these lines in .vimrc for both users:

```
function! Write2Tmp()
    silent! '<,'>w! /tmp/tmp.txt
    call system('chmod 0777 /tmp/tmp.txt > /dev/null 2>&1')
    let g:amount = line("'>") - line("'<") + 1
endfunction

map <silent> <leader>y :call Write2Tmp()<CR>:echo g:amount." lines yanked"<CR>

map <silent> <leader>p :silent! r /tmp/tmp.txt<CR>
```

First enter visual mode (Shift-V) to select the lines you want to copy. Then use <leader>y and <leader>p to copy and paste between files.

Answer (score -1):

In ideal situation it would be great if you could open two files under one instance:

```
vim file1.txt file2.txt
```

If not possible, then you can still do it if the files are accessible on the same host, by opening 1st  file and:

1. Copy text in `file1.txt` (e.g. enter visual mode <kbd>V</kbd>, select the text, and yank/copy them by <kbd>y</kbd>).
2. Open 2nd file by `:Sex`.

   <sup>You may also use: `:e file2.txt`, then if you need to use full path, go to 2nd instance and check by <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.</sup>
3. Paste your text (e.g. <kbd>p</kbd>).

<sup>Above steps can be done opposite, by opening `file2.txt`, then `file1.txt` to copy the text, back to the original file and paste it there.</sup>

Or simply use `screen` buffer to copy and paste between screen windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>]</kbd>).