# How do I get +clipboard support in Fedora 20?

Tags: os-clipboard, x11, linux, installing

It seems to me that neither `"+p` nor `"*p` works for me. How can I know if my Vim is installed and set up properly to make them available? And if it's not set up, what can I do to set it up?

I'm running Fedora 20 with Mate 18.1. I've installed the `vim-enhanced` and `vim-x11` packages.

And my Vim version:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 13 2014 08:56:57)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-475
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      +lua/dyn         +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags  -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker in that case, VtC'ing as "duplicate". That'll give us the "This question already has an answer here (link to your question)" message, which is now fully accurate.

Comment: @yo' I don't think closed as duplicate get auto-deleted.  They shouldn't! Just in case, upvoted so it'll have a positive score.

Comment: @yo' BTW: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/27727 confirms that closed as duplicate don't get auto-deleted. Not sure if there is really much more detailed information to provide (e.g., how to actually install a package using yum/rpm/etc. is probably better asked on [unix.se].)

Comment: (Tried to move to chat, but that just popped up an error. Oh well). @yo' I guess if there is really more to say other than "you need to install `vim-x11` and run `vimx`" ... go ahead and answer it here and I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So, installing `vim-enhanced` and `vim-X11` is enough, but is not at the same time. To enable the system funtcions like `+clipboard`, **you moreover need to use the `vimx` executable rather than `vim` or `vi`** (even though they are probably identical, the name changes the behaviour).

One way how to do that permanently is by adding aliases in your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias vi='vimx'
alias vim='vimx'
```

The complete list of features that get enabled this way is:
`+balloon_eval`,
`+browse`,
`+clientserver`,
`+clipboard`,
`+dnd`,
`+mouseshape`,
`+toolbar`,
`+X11`,
`+xim`,
`+xsmp_interact`,
`+xterm_clipboard`,
`+xpm`.

However, some of them are probably irrelevant for the terminal version of `vimx` and only do something for GVim.

<sub>Information on how to use the `+clipboard` feature is in [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim)</sub>

Comment: I might recommend using "gvim -v" instead of vimx as it's a bit more portable. It works on SuSE Linux where regular vim lacks X11 support and it also won't break on Debian/Ubuntu if used across systems.