# How do I use the system clipboard with Vim in Arch Linux?

Tags: os-clipboard, linux, x11, linux-arch

I am using Vim on Arch Linux through urxvt. Since there is no "Ctrl-V" or "Ctrl-Shift-V" support in urxvt, there is no way for me to paste things I have copied from my browser (let's say) into my vim buffer.

I have `set clipboard=unnamed` in my .vimrc but this seems to have no effect. Pressing "p" only pastes from the vim clipboard and after copying or cutting from vim, nothing gets added to my system clipboard.

Just in urxvt, I can paste by using middle click on the mouse, which uses the system clipboard, but once I enter vim, even this functionality is replaced by vim's internal clipboard.

Is there any way to enable copy-paste functionality in my vim setup?

Comment: Have you looked at http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok. Apparently on native vim in Arch there is no support for X so the `+clipboard` feature is missing. 
To fix this, install `gvim`, which although conflicts with vim, which was my initial problem with it, retains the exact same functionality if you use

```
vim
```

Rather than,

```
gvim
```

You still need to `set clipboard=unnamed`.

Comment: I use Arch Linux, and `has('clipboard')` in `vim` works fine. You *do* need to install the `gvim` package to get a Vim linked to libX11; but you don't need to use `gvim`.

Comment: In other words, uninstall vim, install gvim, run vim. Thanks though, this helped me getting system clipboard working

Comment: Yes! installing gvim from xfce's pamac-manager worked for me on Manjaro 18.1.0