# Compiling Vim from source just enabling clipboard

Tags: os-clipboard, installing

I have a Debian 7.0 with gnome, and I am fully satisfied with the standard vim version installed on it, except for the lack of +clipboard and/or +xterm_clipboard.

I got the sources using mercurial, but I cannot find a way to enable just those.

I have read [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96) or [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416069/compile-vim-with-clipboard-and-xterm). But I don't want to install a full GUI version. It seems overkill to me that I should add all those options just to enable one feature.

Is there a nice way to do it, or should I dive into the code (probably starting from feature.h), to hopefully get what I want..?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you don't need to recompile Vim to enable `+clipboard` on Debian. I don't have a Debian system available, but [when I wrote this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/51) people pointed out that installing the `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome` package should do the trick. The only extra dependency you have for `vim-gtk` will be gtk2 (which you probably already have on most systems anyway). IMHO, the ability to upgrade easily is a lot less effort than installing a few extra dependencies.

Comment: Yes I could get it, but aptitude show vim-gnome shows _This package contains a version of vim compiled with a GNOME2 GUI and support for scripting with Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby, and Tcl._ and GTK, you need to replace GNOME with GTK. So it adds many more feature than the only one I need: +lua, +perl, and gnome/GTK things. Which on a whole would make vim much heavier.

Comment: I did some very basic speed tests of Vim compiled with `--tiny` (almost no features) and `--huge` (all features), and didn't really notice a significant increase in memory or system usage. The tests very very basic, but unless you're noticing performance problems I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Just install vim-gnome or vim-gtk, you won't notice a difference. Except for the presence of clipboard support, that is. Clipboard support depends on  GUI anyway so you don't really have a choice, here. Also, did you try xclip?

Comment: On the [page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard) I have read about xclip and xsel. But I wanted to see if I had an alternative to 1) install options I am not interested in or 2) install a third party program. Reading both of your comments, it looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: Just install the package `vim-athena`. It is a stripped down version of vim-gui and provides `+clipboard` and `+X11`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

vim doesn't need gnome or gtk to get `+clipboard`, but it does need x11. From my tests, the minimum amount of dependencies needed are the xorg header files and x11 dbus support.  In Debian

```
apt-get install x11-dev dbus-x11
```

will do the job. Then you can

```
./configure --with-features=huge
```

and *vioala*, `+clipboard`

Comment: This is not exactly what I was hoping, but it is probably as good as it gets. Indeed from features=normal to features=huge, a few options more options are added. Thanks anyway.