# Copying from Windows clipboard

Tags: microsoft-windows, os-clipboard, mouse

On my Windows 10 box, when using git bash, I am able to righ-click on git bash window and choose paste to flush the contents of the Windows clipboard to my vi text buffer.

Now, when I ssh into a remote machine from this git bash, the vi there catches my right-click, so the Windows pop-up menu does not come up to allow pasting.

How can I paste now from the Windows clipboard?

Comment: Disable the mouse: `set mouse=`

Comment: have you tried `shift+ins` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard

tells me that

> Be aware that copying/pasting from the system clipboard will not work if :echo has('clipboard') returns 0. In this case, vim is not compiled with the +clipboard feature and you'll have to install a different version or recompile it. Some linux distros supply a minimal vim installation by default, but if you install the vim-gtk or vim-gtk3 package you can get the extra features nonetheless.

To compile vim with clipboard, I have found

[Compiling vim from source just enabling clipboard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/compiling-vim-from-source-just-enabling-clipboard)

Comment: If the answer solve your problem maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)