# Set paste mode when at beginning of line but auto-indent mode when anywhere else on the line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

As per other questions, most of us know that if we want to enter paste mode we can toggle `:set paste` and `:set nopaste`.

And for auto-indenting we can `:set autoindent`.

However, I was thinking today, I *only ever paste* when I am at the beginning of a line and otherwise always want auto-indenting. I can set up hot keys to toggle the two quickly, but is there some way perhaps to tell vim in settings to be in paste mode when at the beginning of a line and to otherwise be in auto-indent mode to avoid the need to manually toggle?

Comment: The [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/) plugin has a different (but IMO better) solution.  See Drew Neil's [analysis](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-vims-paste-mode-with-the-system-paste-command/) for the rationale, as well as his [copy and paste series](http://vimcasts.org/categories/copy-and-paste/).

Comment: Better than "paste": "put". Unless you are *really* desperate (tiny vim via ssh without any possibility of X-forwarding), use the * and/or + registers: `"*p`, `"+p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with an auto command ("autocmd"). There's the [`CursorMoved`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorMoved) event which is triggered every time the cursor is moved. `CursorMovedI` does the same, but for insert mode.

```
augroup autopaste
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * let &paste = col('.') == 1
augroup end
```

Or, only on blank lines:

```
augroup autopaste
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * let &paste = getline('.') == ''
augroup end
```

Also see [`:help autocmd.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html) and [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html) (it has more chapters on autocmds, so be sure to look further than just this page).

---

As mentioned in the comments, this *may* not be the best way to do this. Usually pasting directly from the clipboard is more convenient. This can be done fairly easily with these mappings:

```
" Interface with system clipboard
noremap <Leader>y "*y
noremap <Leader>p "*p
noremap <Leader>Y "+y
noremap <Leader>P "+p
```

See [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/51) for more information on how to interface with the system's clipboard.

Comment: Great thanks, going to try this out and then mark this as accepted if it works.