# Syntax highlighting depending on whether whole line is commented

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, folding, comments

Is it possible to have vim highlight folds differently depending on whether every line in a fold is only comments or whitespace? In that case, how?

Comment: Related: [1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9174/51), [2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3650/51), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43953491/660921). Could *probably* adapt this method to folds as well, although getting the contents of the fold is more difficult.