# Copy the full path of current buffer to clipboard

Tags: register, os-clipboard

Is there a quick way to copy the full path of current buffer to system clip board or some register? `:put=expand('%:p')` then use other copy commands(like `dd`) works but the typing is a little long.

Comment: To any register: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916875/yank-file-name-path-of-current-buffer-in-vim

Answer (score 28):

You can assign to the clipboard with the special `+` register:

```
:let @+ = expand('%:p')
```

The `:p` makes it an absolute path; drop it if you want the relative path.

If you want to make this easier, you could create a command, so you only have to type `:CopyBuffer`:

```
:command! CopyBuffer let @+ = expand('%:p')
```

and/or map it to a key:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>c :let @+=expand('%:p')<CR>
```

The post "[How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/51)" has much more information on how to interface with the system's clipboard.

> `:put=expand('%:p')` works but the typing is a little long.

This doesn't copy the path of the buffer to the clipboard, but inserts it in the buffer...?

Comment: Thanks. I meant put into buffer then copy to clipboard or registers via other command.

Comment: @Thomson So you want to do 2 operations in 1 go? Put the filen name in the buffer *and* copy it to the operating system's clipboard?

Comment: I just want to copy the file name of the buffer to clipboard, the previous 2 operations are an crappy workaround.