# Prevent gvim from clearing the clipboard on exit

Tags: cut-copy-paste, gvim, os-clipboard, x11

If I copy text into the xterm clipboard (`"+y`) from gvim, it is cleared when I exit gvim.
How do I prevent this?

I've found the solution for vim, but it doesn't work for **Gvim**:

```
autocmd VimLeave * call system("echo -n $'" . escape(getreg(), "'") . "' | xsel -ib")
```

https://superuser.com/questions/299419/prevent-vim-from-clearing-the-clipboard-on-exit

Comment: Simpler `autocmd`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9381778/2072269. Related: [Can Vim add to the X11 clipboard or primary buffers without an external utility?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3769/205).

Comment: Use a clipboard manager