# How can I reliably copy and paste between vim and other programs?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have a hard time just copying and pasting between vim and other programs (firefox, chrome, gnumeric) as well as other instances of vim.

Normally I try to copy/yank with "+y and paste with "+p. However this sometimes works, and sometimes does not work. I cannot even figure out when it works and when not. One thing which never seems to work is copying from vim, closing vim, then pasting into another program. But sometimes copy/paste even do not work if the original vim instance is still running. I also sometimes try "*y and "*p respectively, with varying results.

If it is relevant, my .vimrc and .screenrc are here: 
https://github.com/antonkratz/fluffy-tribble

How can I *reliably* copy and paste between vim and other programs, and other instances of vim?

==

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 31 2015 23:36:07)

xfce4-terminal 0.6.3, under Xubuntu.

Comment: If you close Vim before pasting, that won't work. See http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3770/205. If Vim is still running, it should work. However, if you copied to the primary (`*`) instead of the clipboard (`+`), even selecting text somewhere else could overwrite that. For me, using `+` works reliably.

Comment: I suspect this question is actually a dupe of yours @muru?