# No + or * register on Linux (accessed via SSH from macOS)?

Tags: register, macos, os-clipboard, ssh

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.3 and Vim 8.2. I'm trying to figure out how to access either the `*` or `+` clipboard on Ubuntu but it seems like it doesn't exist? After doing `"*yy` and `"+yy` on lines of text, here is what it shows:

```
:reg + *
Type Name Content
[empty]
```

Neither `+` or `*` exists in there. It seems like it's set to use the `unnamedplus` register:

```
:echom has('unnamedplus') 
" 1

:echom has('unnamed')
" 0
```

Then I try doing (again):

```
:set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

And doing `"+yy` again, but still nothing shows up in the register. Is there no 'system clipboard' on ubuntu (accessible by vim), or if so, how can I get that to work?

Also, I've verified my vim is compiled with both clipboard-related options:

```
+xterm_clipboard
+clipboard
+X11
```

Comment: Do you also have the feature `+X11`?

Comment: Please provide more information about your system. Did you start a X-server? Is $DISPLAY correctly set? Are you doing anything unusual, like ssh'ing to a different server?

Comment: @Ralf yes, that as well (updated question with it)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yes, I am ssh'ing **into** the Ubuntu server from my local Mac. How can I check display and x-server? And, what other system information do you want to provide (and how can I get that info?)

Comment: Well, if you are using ssh, things are very much complicated. Make sure that $DISPLAY is correctly set, and you need to use `ssh -Y` or `ssh -X` for that to work reliable (or the ForwardX11 config option set or whatever it is called). Then you probably also need to be run a local X11 server on your mac (I don't know Mac so this might be wrong). There are probably already questions about this, please search

Comment: probably a duplicate of this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/71

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822357/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-to-copy-from-vim-to-local-machine

Comment: We already have a lot of similar question [example](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10868/1841), [example](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8354/1841) and an [authoritative answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/1841) so I'll close this one. If despite the information in these links you still don't find a solution please edit your question to show exactly what is different from these other ones and cast a vote to reopen the question.