# Paste clipboard shortcut in vimrc

Tags: cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard

I know that I can paste the clipboard in by by typing <kbd>ctrl-shift-v</kbd>.

The problem is that this is a very counterintuitive shortcut. It requires me to move my hand in a very uncomfortable way.

I would like to paste the clipboard with something better, such as `gcp`.

I am trying to put a line in my vimrc file that will accomplish this, but I am getting major headaches as it seems to be impossible to do. Instead I must resort to some buffers, which i have been looking at for a while without result.

How do I place a line in the Vimrc which allows me to paste the clipboard content onto the file I'm in, upon a click of a shortcut of my choosing?

p.s.
Solution was to install vim-gtk
and after that i could do:
:put +

Comment: in which mode do you need?

Comment: for normal mode.

Comment: so try `nnoremap gcp "+p`

Comment: I go to the url of the browser, highlight it, copy it by doing ctrl-c. Then i go into vim and would like to paste it there via shortcut, so i try doing "+p in normal mode and all i get printed is "

Comment: check this out: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim

Comment: i am wading through that for quite a while and not finding the answer.

Comment: check the section `No +clipboard?`

Comment: youre right. i installed vim-gtk and then :put + pastes the clipboard successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update: In order to access the system clipboard(s) Vim needs to be compiled with support for this. You can use the commands `:echo has('clipboard')` and, on Unix, `:echo has('xterm_clipboard')` to check for this. As it turns out, question asker did* not *have these features compiled in. Their `ctrl-shift-v` shortcut was pasting into the* terminal *and Vim was receiving the text as if it were typed. [This existing question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim) describes how to get the system clipboard accessible from within Vim.*

The standard method of pasting from the system clipboard is via the `+` register, which you can access from normal mode with a command such as `"+p`. (Outside of X11 sytems, the `*` register will also work. See `:help x11-selection` for a discussion of the difference.)

You can therefore create your `gcp` mapping for normal/visual/select modes with the commands:

```
:nnoremap gcp "+p
:noremap gcp "+p
```

The following works for insert mode (see `:help i_CTRL-O`), but `gcp` isn't the best choice of trigger in insert mode, for obvious reasons, so you're probably going to want to pick something else:

```
:inoremap gcp <c-o>"+p
```

N.B. `ctrl-shift-v` is not a standard Vim shortcut, and as far as I'm aware, [such a shortcut can only be set up *outside* of Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506764/how-to-map-ctrla-and-ctrlshifta-differently). Is there any chance you're on Windows, you have `clipboard=unnamed` set, and you're actually just using `mswin.vim's` `ctrl-v` shortcut?

Comment: Im on linux. I go to the url of the browser, highlight it, copy it by doing ctrl-c. Then i go into vim and would like to paste it there via shortcut, so i try doing "+p in normal mode and all i get printed is "

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Terminal Vim or GUI Vim? What is the output of `:echo has('clipboard')`?

Comment: terminal vim. the output of the echo is 0.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson What about `:echo has('xterm_clipboard')`

Comment: that returns 0 as well.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson If that is the case, your version of Vim does not appear to be compiled with clipboard support. I'm not sure how your `ctrl-shift-v` command is working *from normal mode*.

Comment: Its only working in insert mode.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson In that case, Vim doesn't know you're pasting at all. You're pasting into your terminal, and Vim sees it as if it were being typed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47175/discussion-between-rich-and-hermann-ingjaldsson).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Vim has access to the clipboard, you can insert the clipboard contents (in Vim register `+`) via `<C-R><C-R>+` (in insert mode) and via `"+p` in other modes.

Thus, some mappings could be:

```
:noremap <F2> "+p
:noremap! <F2> <C-R><C-R>+
```

To paste as completely new lines, you can also use

```
:put +
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second mapping be `inoremap`?

Comment: @statox: `:map!` combines `:imap` and `:cmap`; this might be useful in the command-line as well. See `:help map-modes`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Hmm. Shouldn't the first one `nnoremap`, though?