# System clipboard not working via ssh

Tags: os-clipboard, ssh

I work on a remote server and would like to yank stuff to the server's clipboard. However `"+y` gives me an error flash (visual terminal bell) and when quitting vim, I can't paste in the terminal.

Maybe this is an issue with ssh not correctly transmitting `Ctrl-Shift-V`?

Comment: The clipboard is managed by the X server, which is presumably running on your local machine. Applications such as vim running on the remote server won't be able to contact the local X server (and use the clipboard) unless you forward the X connection over your ssh channel. To do that, you'll need to run ssh with the `-Y` or `-X` option, or put `ForwardX11Trusted = yes` or `ForwardX11 = yes` in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: @garyjohn It is not my intention to copy and paste between local and remote clipboard, but simply from remote vim to remote system clipboard. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: No, you didn't misunderstand me. Unless I'm missing something, there is no mechanism to copy and paste from a remote system clipboard. The X-aware applications that you run on the remote server via ssh do not communicate with any remote X server--they communicate with the local X server if X traffic is being forwarded over the ssh connection.

Comment: But when I start vim in an ssh session, this instance should have a `+` register, right? Even if pasting from it outside vim doesn't work, why would it error when trying to use that register?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I see a flash which is what my terminal does when something errors. I don't know where vim keeps logs of such events.

Comment: Oh, right. That's called the *terminal bell*. I thought you got an actual error... Do you have an X11 server running on the machine you're ssh-ing to? Is Vim compiled with `+clipboard`?

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I checked for the `clipboard` feature previously and forgot this was indeed not in the binary. I guess we have a culprit.

Comment: So I guess that makes this question a duplicate of [our most upvoted question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/1841)?