# How to merge OS'es clipboard with Vim's one?

Tags: buffers, os-clipboard

How can I merge OS clipboard and Vim's one? I want them to be the same, so **that I don't have to use** `"*y` or `"*p` or `"*d`, instead just `y`, or `p` or `d`. How can I do that?

Comment: See http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/89/205

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. See the [help/behavior] before responding further.

Comment: Note that the linked question should contain the answer: *"If you want to "automatically" interface with the system's clipboard instead of referring to it manually all the time, you can set the clipboard variable: [...]"*

Answer (score 2):

From [`:h 'cb`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#clipboard-unnamed):

```
                    *clipboard-unnamed*
unnamed     When included, Vim will use the clipboard register '*'
        for all yank, delete, change and put operations which
        would normally go to the unnamed register.  When a
        register is explicitly specified, it will always be
        used regardless of whether "unnamed" is in 'clipboard'
        or not.  The clipboard register can always be
        explicitly accessed using the "* notation.  Also see
        |gui-clipboard|.
```

So, maybe you could try to prepend the value `'unnamed'` to the option `'clipboard'`:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed
```

As the help explains, this should tell Vim to use the `*` register for all yank, delete, change and put operations.

Comment: why maybe? will that work for sure?

Comment: @Torito I said maybe because I'm not using exactly this setting. I'm using this : `set clipboard^=unnamedplus`. It should work, but it can lead to problems if you're using plugins. Often, plugin authors forget to take into consideration that the user may change their `'clipboard'` option. Because of this, sometimes a functionality they provide doesn't work as expected. Here is an example: https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease/blob/master/plugin/scriptease.vim#L251 Here, you just have to prepend `""` in front of the `p` command, but still, it can be annoying to find where the fix is needed.