# How to set system cut-buffer clipboard as default in vim?

Tags: buffers, register, os-clipboard

I usually want to share my clipboard between vim and other applications (like a web browser) so that I can yank/paste the information easily.

So questions,

1. How do I set the default behavior of vim to **always** use **only** the system `X11 cut-buffer` and **never** use the selection buffer? means settig default `d`, `y`, `p` keys to directly utilize `"+` register.
2. Would it have any side-effects if I am totally deserting the use of `"*` register? Are there any significant use of `"*` register?

Comment: `:h 'clipboard'`

Comment: This question sounds like [a duplicate](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/1841) to me.