# Make vim support the Windows clipboard

Tags: cut-copy-paste, microsoft-windows, os-clipboard

I've found a lot of information online about this for Linux-Vim but not for the Windows-Vim (not gvim). Whenever I try to copy and paste something in Vim (using `y` and `p`), the copies I make do not expand to the system, only to the currently running instance of vim. Here are a few different scenarios that all do different things:

1. Copying-and-pasting like normal in the command prompt (by highlighting to copy and right-clicking to paste) works as expected - it copies to and pastes from the system clipboard
2. If I copy `abc` in notepad, I can paste `abc` in any opened vim with `p` or `"*p` or `"+p`. But if I copy `123` from one instance of vim with `y`, `"+y`, or `"*y`, I can paste `123` in that instance, but if I switch to another, `abc` will paste instead of `123`.

Based on what I've read, this is because Vim places the data in a register, but the register doesn't get transferred to the windows clipboard. However, I haven't been able to find any information online about why, everything is limited to the Linux version.

I've tried using `:set guioptions+=a` as mentioned [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim) but that doesn't seem to work. Also, `+clipboard` returns 1, so I believe it should be enabled.

Comment: Just to be sure: when you yank and paste your text do you specify the register like `"*y` `"*p`?

Comment: @statox Yes, I've added those details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Windows machine to test, but I think you are looking for

```
:set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

Than Vim always uses the `+` register "for all yank, delete, change and put operations which would normally go to the unnamed register".

See `:help clipboard`.

Answer (score 1):

> I've found a lot of information online about this for Linux-Vim but not for the Windows-Vim (not gvim).

There's no much difference really, except Windows has only one clipboard, so both `*` and `+` could be used interchangeably.

> If I copy abc in notepad, I can paste abc in any opened vim with p or "*p or "+p

Just `p` uses so-called unnamed register, which is basically an alias for the last register used. That means it may *accidentally* work for the system clipboard, but, in general, it does not. On the other hand, both `"*p` and `"+p` always put the contents of the system clipboard at the cursor position.

> But if I copy 123 from one instance of vim with y, "+y, or "*y

The same, of course, applies to yanking. The unnamed register, in general, is not visible outside of the current instance of Vim. But `+` and `*` are.