# Problem copying form vim to system clipboard

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste

I usually do this with `"*y` (from visual mode), but on the linux box I'm working with (lubuntu) when I press `*` after `"` in visual mode, vim doesn't insert `*` (it just ignores the whole `"*`). If I check `*` register with `:reg`, I find it empty. There must be some option which interferes. I checked `mkvimrc`, but didn't find any map instruction which involved `*`.

Comment: Have you read [How can I copy text to the system clipboard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/1841)? Especially have you checked `echo has('clipboard')`?

Comment: @statox I should have seen that, sorry. It was missing the gtk version of vim, now ti works.

Comment: No problem :) I'll just close your question as a duplicate