# Copy all text in Vi and then paste it to another application on another system

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I connect to Linux server via SSH using Putty terminal.
I open a file with Vim and press `ggVGy` in order to select all text and copy it.
But when I try to paste the copied text to Windows Notepad, it turns out that the clipboard is empty.
How to properly copy text from Vim on Linux and paste it to another app on Windows?
Please note that I am able to copy and paste parts of the text from Vim to Windows Notepad - Putty terminal is configured in such a way that the selected text is automatically copied to the clipboard. The problem occurs only when I want to copy all the text with `ggVGy` combination in a file and the file big enough so that it needs several `PageDown` key hits in order to get to the bottom of it.

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jul 16 2019 20:50:52)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
```

Comment: We have a couple of closely related questions [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/copy-paste-selection-locally-when-editing-files-on-remote-headless-server) and [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim) (See the SSH section).

Comment: in such a special case, I usually copy the file manually over using winscp or such (note, Vim comes with netrw, which might be able to directly connect to your remote server and edit that file locally as well, I have never done that however9.