# How to remap copy and pasting to keyboard

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to remap the current keybindings to make it simpler for yanking and pasting but it doesn't work.

Some of my ~/.vimrc

```
noremap <Leader>Y "*y
noremap <Leader>P "*p
noremap <Leader>y "+y
noremap <Leader>p "+p
```

None of them do anything, I have to use the original keybindings

Comment: Shouldn’t it be nnoremap?

Comment: What means " doesn't work"? Do you know what is your `mapleader` set to? Do you really press that key first?

Comment: To me your question will either be solved by [how to use the clipboard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/1841) or [how to debug a mappin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841). Given that you didn't included any details about what you tried to do, what your system is, what are your compilation options, what behavior you expect vs what behavior you get and these kind of useful information I'm closing the question as duplicate. If it's not feel free to edit it and then vote to reopen it.