# I Have a Problem with Premature Yanking

Tags: cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard

If I've already yanked 37 lines, is there a way to send them to the clipboard without having to select them again?

I need to move those yanked lines into a GUI application.

Comment: Extremely related [how can I copy to the system clipboard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I’m going to go ahead and infer from your use of the word “select”, that you yanked via visual mode.

If that’s the case, then you can use `gv` to reselect the previous selection. You can then yank to the clipboard as usual `"+y`.

Comment: Additionally, the `gv` is enough to put it in PRIMARY selection on systems using X11 (e.g. linux). So, one can `gv` then middle-click to paste. One can also use a clipboard manager that synchronizes the clipboard and primary selection to paste with Ctrl+v.

Comment: @JoL I had no idea that the last visual selection was available in the primary selection on linux! Thank you for this!

Comment: @Quasímodo `:h clipboard-unnamed` is not needed for what I described, but it seems like a good, related, additional feature. With it, apparently not only are visual selections immediately available in PRIMARY selection, but also the text that's yanked, deleted, changed, or put without involving visual selection.

Comment: Checking the other possible values of `:h clipboard`, what I described in my first comment is controlled by `:h clipboard-autoselect`, further down is `:h clipboard-autoselectplus` which is similar, but puts the visual selection automatically in the OS CLIPBOARD, the one that's pasted with Ctrl+v.

Comment: For anyone else with this issue, make sure that you have your Vim compiled with the "+clipboard" setting. This allows it to access system clipboard. You can check whether this is set with `vim --version`. If the default `vim` from your package manager doesn't have +clipboard, you might try the `vim` that is installed along with the `gvim` package -- that usually does.

Answer (score 22):

The `+` and `*` registers can be used to access the clipboard; and you can assign values to registers with `let @<register-name>`. For example if you've pressed `y` to yank text to the `"0` register:

```
:let @+ = @0
```

If you're using Windows or macOS then `@+` and `@*` are identical and it doesn't matter which one you use; if you're using Xorg then `@*` is the mouse middle click clipboard (PRIMARY) and `@+` is the the `<C-v>` clipboard (CLIPBOARD). I'm actually not sure how Wayland works with this.

[How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/51) has some more information about Vim and clipboards, which might be useful.

Comment: I did post an answer, but your way is much more direct - so now I'm using it instead of the less elegant maps I was using. Thanks!

Comment: `not sure how Wayland works with this` FYI, Wayland is a set of protocols. Any composer/server must support only core protocols featuring a single "clipboard". Anything else is optional and is not included into reference implementation. In practice, a second clipboard may be supported by 3rd party composers using custom protocol(s).

Comment: FWIW, I see the same behavior in X and Wayland.

Answer (score 3):

I have the following maps in my .vimrc to do just that (i.e. after I've prematurely yanked... copy the yanked text into my system clipboard by pressing `<LEADER>y/Y`, where leader is by default the `\` key):

```
" copy contents of unnamed register to system CTRL-C clipboard
nnoremap <silent> <LEADER>y :let @+=@0<CR>
            \ :echo 'copied to CTRL-C clipboard'<CR>

" copy contents of unnamed register to system highlighted clipboard
nnoremap <silent> <LEADER>Y :let @*=@0<CR>
            \ :echo 'copied to highlight clipboard'<CR>
```

As pointed out by @MartinTournoij, if you're using Windows or macOS then these two maps are identical and you can just use one of them.

Answer (score 3):

A pair of simple mappings for all who suffer:

```
" - to set unnamed register
nmap - <cmd>call setreg('@',
    \ #{points_to: v:register is '"' ? v:count % 10 : v:register})<CR>
" + to set clipboard register
nmap + <cmd>call setreg('+',
    \ getreginfo(v:register is '"' ? v:count % 10 : v:register))<CR>
```

"Plus" key to set clipboard register (to cure premature yanking):

- `+` to set clipboard to "zero" register (last yank);
- `1+` to set clipboard to "one" register (last delete);
- `"-+` to set clipboard to "minus" register (last small delete); etc.

"Minus" key to set unnamed register (to cure premature deletion):

- `-` to point unnamed to "zero" register (last yank);
- `1-` to point unnamed to "one" register (last delete);
- `"--` to point unnamed to "minus" register (last small delete); etc.