# Vim only sometimes choosing to copy to system keyboard

Tags: os-clipboard

I have the following situation. If I open a file in Vim, say by running `vim myfile.tex`, select something in visual mode, and do `"+y`, it is in the system clipboard as one would hope. If however I open a project, say `vim -S myproject.vim`, in which the same files are open, `"+y` does not change the system clipboard. This behavior is actually new; it did not do it before yesterday. I did not to my knowledge change anything in the configuration in the intervening period.

My current default Vim does return `-clipboard` among other things from `vim --version`, so I suppose I am lucky it works in even setting, but I am reluctant to switch to a different version of Vim because I switched to the present one because another extension was broken. The computer is running Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Which platform are you using? Did you close the Vim window before you tried to paste things?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim)

Comment: No, I know how to do that. The issue initially was that that `vnoremap Y "+y` was not behaving as expected, but I realized afterward that generally, `"+yy` was not functioning, but only within a project, like `vim -S myproject.vim`; in the context `vim myfile.tex` it was working just fine. I have checked `:vim --version` on both versions, and it comes up with `-clipboard`, so one wouldn't expect it to work at all, but it does work consistently when I simply open a file.

Comment: @MartinTournoij, my apologies, I wrote a response yesterday and then presumably lost connection before I hit "Add comment." I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I had not closed the terminal tab running Vim.

Comment: Might be worth trying [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) on your vimrc and on the session file

Comment: 1. If it has `-clipboard` and still changes the clipboard then it has some mapping for `y`; 2. If it only works after `-S foobar.vim` then `&ssop` has `options` flag set and that mapping was saved into session file (but it's not in vimrc).